# How to pass a parameter with space in its name to store procedure in vba access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am using vba access and SQL server. I have a form in which there is a field named `Material ID` with a space. Now, I am trying to pass this in the Store Procedure but I am not sure how do I actually pass it. Code I have been working on is:

```
If frm.Tag Then
    strFilter = "usp_MovePending '" & UserStr & "'"
    strFilter = strFilter & "," & frm!MaterialID  

    DB.QueryDefs("qryMovePending").Connect = SQLConnectString
    DB.QueryDefs("qryMovePending").ReturnsRecords = False
    DB.QueryDefs("qryMovePending").sql = strFilter
    DB.QueryDefs("qryMovePending").Execute dbFailOnError
End If
```

In above code, I used `frm!MaterialID` without space which obviously gave me an error saying `Microsoft access can't find the field 'MaterialID' referred to in your expression`. And when I keep `[frm!Material ID]` with space, it doesn't return anything. I also tried keeping single quote around it but it returned single quote with no value. Please help.

Comment: frm![Material ID]? frm("Material ID") ?

Comment: Also frm.Material_ID. I believe access replaces spaces with an underscore.

Comment: Protip: don't use spaces or special characters in field names.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Ya, but for this case, someone else used it like a decade ago.

Comment: If the code is being run from the form then in the VBA editor type in Me. and you will get the forms available control names via intellisense. 
ProTip 2: Don't accept the default control names - so on this form change it to txtMaterialID them you know exactly what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the **square bracket** as delimiter ...

```
frm![Material ID]
```

Comment: I had already tried that one too, it doesn't return anything for materialid.

Comment: above you have mentioned you tried only with '[frm!Material ID]'.... which is different

Comment: leave the form name outside the square bracket

Comment: I had tried this one too. It still returns nothing.

Comment: Then I guess there might be problem with the actual data/code... try it with some other value of field to confirm whether the code works for other cases...

Comment: When I kept `MaterialNumber` , it showed me 'NULL' while hovering on `MaterialNumber` during debug but it gave me nothing in my pass-through parameters i.e. `usp_MovePending 'administrator',''`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the Access object model, but in VBA/VB6 the *bang notation* `foo!bar` is shorthand for the explicit notation:

```
foo("bar").Value
```

In other words, `frm!Foobar` is shorthand for this:

```
frm("Foobar").Value
```

So you would do:

```
frm("Material ID").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly added a underscore to it - try using the Me.Material_ID or Me.[Material ID] to refer to the actual forms control name. Value is the default property